# Using Text As a Point Marker in a Line Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to make the points in a C# `Chart` show up as letters (e.g. 'A' and 'B') to separate sets of points, instead of coloring them with green/red. 
The `Label` property of the point collection does not satisfy this request, since it only places labels *beside* the point, and I want the label to *replace* the point.

Here is what I have:

```
while (reader.Read())
{                    
    if (reader[2].ToString() == "Kupi 002")
        chart3.Series["Good_Group"].Points[pointsCounter].Label = "A";
    else
        chart3.Series["Good_Group"].Points[pointsCounter].Label = "B";
    pointsCounter = pointsCounter + 1;
}
```

What property, instead of `Label`, should I use to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the PostPaint event to add stuff that the built-in graphs do not support.

Comment: You can use Markers or Annotations for this. A screenshot always help to understand what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `MarkerImage` property of either the series or point to apply custom bitmap labels of each letter:

[image: A][image: B]

```
chart.Series[0].MarkerImage = "a.png";
chart.Series[0].Points[2].MarkerImage = "b.png";
chart.Series[0].Points[4].MarkerImage = "b.png";
```

[image: Chart with letter labels]

The bitmap images could be created in a paint program and distributed with your program. They could also be generated dynamically, as in the following (highly simplified) example:

```
private void CreateLetterBitmap(char letter, string path)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(13, 13))
    using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    {
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        gfx.DrawString(letter.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 0));
        bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}

private void PrepareChart()
{
    CreateLetterBitmap('A', "a.png");
    CreateLetterBitmap('B', "b.png");

    chart.Series[0].MarkerImage = "a.png";
    chart.Series[0].Points[2].MarkerImage = "b.png";
    chart.Series[0].Points[4].MarkerImage = "b.png";
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your code, but in my system, TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias is not recognize.. I have the name space Drawing, you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure to include the namespace `System.Drawing.Text`